# Getting the exact order from Tree Table - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, treetable

[image]

From: https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Tree-Table-Plugin-Bootstrap-GTreeTable.html

It doesn't necessarily need to be this example, it's just to illustrate. It's so simple, but my friends and I can't find a solution ...

We need to get the exact order of the user when he puts this data into the form, such as:

1. Insert Father
2. Insert Child
3. Insert Father 2
4. Insert Child 2 (from Father)
5. Insert Child (from Father 2)

So I need to insert this order in my SQL

Comment: I don't really understand the order you're looking for, but if you're talking about entering data into a table in a specific order you need to understand that SQL Server doesn't store data ordered.  If you can't query your data in the order you want based on the the data itself you'll need to add another column (SortOrder or something like that) in order to provide the query with the desired ordering.

Comment: For you to understand better I will create an example, I have a table of names, I want to insert the data in this table in the order in which the user creates new rows in this table. Like my example = 1: Father, 2: Child, 3: Father 2, 4: Child 2 (from Father), 5: Child (from Father 2)

Comment: I just need a logic, I'm thinking of C # and not SQL